# ElementNotVisibleException Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando fazer o login no site www.pactpub.com

usando a seguinte ideia

```
def setUp(self):

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\_workspace\projects\Packtpub\chromedriver')
    self.driver.get("https://www.packtpub.com")
    time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!


def test_login(self):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.maximize_window()

    login1 = driver.find_element_by_id("email-wrapper")
    login1.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("my_login")
```

porem ele não consegue encontrar o campo de email

e retorna o erro:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

como posso contornar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é bem claro: o elemento que você está tentando selecionar não está visível. Isso pode ser causado por alguns fatores como: a visibilidade do elemento depende de determinada ação na página ou o elemento simplesmente ainda não terminou de ser carregado.

Em todo caso, você pode tentar aguardar até o elemento ficar visível, da seguinte forma:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

espera = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID,'email-wrapper')))
```

Com isso você define um limite de até 10 segundos de espera até que o elemento "email-wrapper" torne-se visível. Você também pode utilizar essa mesma lógica para transformar seu time.sleep(5) em algo mais funcional.

Referência sobre esperas no Selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Você precisa corrigir o exemplo. No você instancia o `WebDriverWait` na variavel espera e abaixo usa uma variável `wait`. No caso o `wait` seria o `espera`.